# How to deploy a Powershell 2.0 custom host application on a machine with no PowerShell installed?

Tags: powershell

I've developed a Powershell custom host application and want to deploy it on a machine with no powershell installed. I added "System.Management.Automation.dll" in the package to deploy and have a reference to it in my C# project. However, it seems not working. At least, when I tried to build the application on that machine, it failed to locate the Automation assembly. Any suggestions?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PowerShell engine is not restributable as an assembly, neither technically or legally. Karl Prosser goes into this a few years ago, and nothing appears to have changed since.

http://karlprosser.com/coder/2008/06/17/portable-powershell-v1-and-v2-side-by-side-even-on-server-core/

Comment: From Karl Prosser's blog, karlprosser.com/coder/2010/06/16/…, it seems Microsoft already eased the restriction on redistributing powershell engine. Anyone has a link to such information from Microsoft?

Comment: The engine is more than sys.man.automation.dll. There are multiple DLLs, and windows services (e.g. winrm)

Comment: I consider this answers my question, because Mr Karl Prosser's blog is quite clear about this, and they do have shown us an example of distributing custom PowerShell host application.

Comment: Actually, it needs the resources file along with the dll. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

When you are building MSBuild or VS needs to find the assembly, they have rules about where to search: check the hint path in the project file (or the properties of the reference in VS).

However I expect you'll still have problems, PowerShell is installed as a system component and is likely to have much deeper dependencies on updates the installer includes. Far better to install PowerShell on both target and development systems, any other route is just going to lead to issues.